# Find class with methods with the same name

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find files in visual studio code whose content have a class with methods with the same names. For instance, the following content should match:

```
class Hello {
    ...
    function Hello() { ... }
    ...
}
```

In any case, I tried to make my regex for this `class\s([A-Za-z_]+)[^]*(function\s\1)` and it seems to work fine. When I try to search for a file in visual studio code it throws an error that says: "inverse references are not allowed".

Is there an easy way to do what I want here? Is my regex badly formed?

Comment: It is badly formed. Replace `[^]` with `[\s\S\r]`. Does `class\s([A-Za-z_]+)[\s\S\r]*(function\s\1)` match what you need?

Comment: Well, I tried with `class\s([A-Za-z_]+)[\s\S\r]*(function\s\1)` and it doesn't work on visual studio

Comment: Is it Visual Studio or VSCode? I have just tried `class\s+([A-Za-z_]+)[\s\S\r]*(function\s\1\b)` and it works perfectly in Visual Studio S&R.

Comment: It is visual studio code, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `[^]` with `[\s\S\r]`.

The pattern that should work is

```
class\s([A-Za-z_]+)[\s\S\r]*(function\s\1)
```

Or, probably a more precise version:

```
class\s+([A-Za-z_]+)\b[\s\S\r]*?(function\s+\1\b)
       ^            ^^         ^              ^^
```

**Details**

- `class` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z_]+)` - Group 1: 1 or more letters or `_`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[\s\S\r]*?` - any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `(function\s+\1\b)` - Group 2: `fuinction`,  1+ whitespaces, Group 1 value and a word boundary.

[image]

Comment: Seems good. In any case, does it work if you try to search files with that content? Because I'm using the regex in "search files" context (I'm not trying to find inside a specific file) and the regex doesn't match any file. FYI, I have a lot of that kind of files, so at least 350 should match

Comment: @TomásJuárez The "Find in Files" regex engine uses Rust regex engine that does not support backreferences. I think you cannot use your regex in Find in Files. Note you may use the same feature in Notepad++ though (it also has Find in Files dialog).

Comment: I tried using VSCode and Atom and neither of the two worked. The only one text editor that could find the files for me in that way is SublimeText 3. So, your regex worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @TomásJuárez Great, yeah, Suiblime Text 3 is PCRE powered, it will work with lookarounds and backreferences.